# Abaqus python script, how to 'addData' for elements with multiple integration points (e.g. C3D20R)

Tags: python, numpy, abaqus

I have the following piece of code:

```
from abaqus import *
from odbAccess import *
from abaqusConstants import *
import visualization
import fileinput
import os
import shutil
import numpy as np
from odbAccess import *


def tupled_list(mylist,n):
    '''group  every n elements of the list into a tuple '''    
    return list(zip(*[iter(mylist)]*n))

# Open odb
odb_filename = 'AbaqusResults.odb'
work_directory=os.getcwd()
odb_filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'..','outputs',odb_filename))

my_odb=session.openOdb(name=odb_filepath,readOnly=FALSE)

# Automate the proces of reading the step no matter what its name is
StepNames=(my_odb.steps.keys() )        
lastStep=( StepNames[-1] )              

# Automation of an instance naming (in the same way)
AllInstances = (my_odb.rootAssembly.instances.keys())
MyInstance = ( AllInstances[-1] ) 
SubmodelInstance=my_odb.rootAssembly.instances[MyInstance]

# Get dataset containing element labels and calculated quantities in here from text file
dataset = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'AbaqusDataInput.txt'),delimiter=',')

# List of all element labels
elLabels = dataset[0,:].astype(int).tolist()

# Count the number of integration points for a single element
gausspoints = elLabels.count(1)

# Get damage data from dataset and format into a list of tuples, tuple length depends on number of integration points for eache element
damage = tupled_list(list(dataset[1,:]),gausspoints)
damage = [list(elem) for elem in damage]

# Remove duplicates from elLabel list
elLabels = list(set(elLabels))


for i in range(len(my_odb.steps[lastStep].frames)):
    new_field_damage = my_odb.steps[lastStep].frames[i].FieldOutput(name='Damage',description='Damage sustained after one repitition of the loading history', type=SCALAR)
    new_field_damage.addData(position=INTEGRATION_POINT, instance=SubmodelInstance, labels=elLabels, data=damage)


my_odb.save() 
my_odb.close()
```

but I get the following error:

```
Data at 141968 locations expected. Data at 17746 locations provided. Element data request failed. Element type is C3D20R. Data at 8 integration points per element expected
```

elLabels is a list with 17746 items and
damage is a tuple list with 17746 items but each item has 8 values (one for each integration point) e.g. [(x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x) , (x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x), … ]

Thus I provide abaqus with 17746 element labels and 17746 * 8 locations (141968 data points in total as asked) so I don’t see why I get the error.

I have tried a list of lists instead of a list of tuples but the same error occurs. I suspect is merely an issue of using the correct datatypes but the Abaqus documentation seems severely lacking.

The script works fine for odb files with C3D8R elements which have 1 integration point. I then provide the same elLabels list and damage list but then each tuple only has 1 value (e.g. [(x, ) (x, ), … ] ) which works fine.

Do you know how I can import my data into the elements integration points?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I stumbled across a similar problem. The correct format seems to be just plain lists:

```
elLabels = [1, 2, ...]
damage = [1_1, 1_2, 1_3, 1_4, 1_5, 1_6, 1_7, 1_8, 2_1, 2_2, ...]
```

where i_j is the data of element i at integration point j.

By the way, it's probably better to remove duplicates like this to maintain a correct order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(elLabels))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can first try to confirm if the data in Abaqus is indeed stored in element sequence first followed by integration point sequence within an element. For example for S4R type, the stresses of S22 are stored for the bottom surface of all elements, and then for the top surface of all elements. That is, they are not in sequence of element 1(bottom, top), element2(bottom, top)....element n(bottom top); rather, it is: bottom (element1), bottom (element2)...bottom (element n), top(element1), top(element2).. top (element n)

try:

`S22_ES = (o1.steps[LoadStep].frames[loadDir+1].fieldOutputs['S'].getScalarField(componentLabel="S22") .getSubset(region=Elset,position=INTEGRATION_POINT,))`

Comment: try  S22_ES = (o1.steps[LoadStep].frames[loadDir+1].fieldOutputs['S'].getScalarField(componentLabel="S22")
    .getSubset(region=Elset,position=INTEGRATION_POINT,))